# Display the content of parent page in SilverStripe

Tags: silverstripe

I have simple tree structure in SilverStripe.

**ParentPage and ChildPage.**

On ParentPage I display the list of ChildPages. But I don't want to make accessible url:

***/parent-page/child-page***

I want to allow only

***/parent-page***

That's why I did redirect in ChildPage index action to ParentPage:

```
class ChildPage_Controller extends Page_Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        $this->redirect('/parent-page/');
    }

}
```

It works well on frontend. But in CMS after I click to ChidPage in tree, it redirects me editing the ParentPage. (not to frontend url but to admin/pages/edit/show/ParentPageID ). This happen only in Split or Preview mode.

Can you advice how to prevent it? Or is there some other option? Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

so finally I found the solution.

Preview pane is displayed in an iframe. And parent CMS frame binds for changing the url of preview pane. It's because when you click to some link in preview pane, CMS navigates you to edit that page. So also when I do the redirect from ChildPage to ParentPage, the CMS pane catches the change of url and editor is redirected to the ParentPage.

I haven't found the way, how to prevent it, finally I needed to edit javascript of CMS (LeftAndMain.Preview.js line 251).

```
iframe.bind('load', function() {

                self._adjustIframeForPreview();

                // Load edit view for new page, but only if the preview is activated at the moment.
                // This avoids e.g. force-redirections of the edit view on RedirectorPage instances.


                // self._loadCurrentPage();

                $(this).removeClass('loading');
            });
```

So I commented out this line "self._loadCurrentPage();"

In the comment was written *"This avoids e.g. force-redirections of the edit view on RedirectorPage instances."* But it did the redirect anyway.

Maybe there's better way how to do that, but I haven't found it.

Comment: Hacking core files kills your ability to upgrade. If at all possible, you should look into overriding the behavior via entwine in custom js.

Answer (score 1):

In the `init` function you can check if the user has permission to view the CMS and if the page currently has the *stage* get variable set:

```
class ChildPage_Controller extends Page_Controller {

    public function init() {
        parent::init();
        if (!($this->getRequest()->getVar('stage') && Permission::check('VIEW_CMS'))) {
            return $this->redirect($this->Parent()->Link(), 301);
        }
    }

}
```

This way a normal user will be redirected and a CMS user that isn't viewing the page with *?stage=...* set will be redirected. The preview / split panes always set the *stage* get variable so the page will never be redirected when viewed in the preview / split pane.

Comment: thanks for answer, but I would like to redirect the preview pane, but keep CMS  on current edited page. But I know the solution now, will write it in the answer.